# Bootstrap: Is it possible to create a template that can be imported to each new page on a website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, web-frontend

I'm using Bootstrap to create a personal website/blog. I am sort of new to this framework, and to web-development in general, so I'd appreciate some pointers.
I'd like any new page I add to have the same layout: side navigation menu taking up 3 columns, and the contents taking up the remaining 9. In small format, I'll have them each taking up the full 12 columns. 
I'd like to make this template because if I decide to change my site layout one day, I don't want to have to go through each individual file to do so. 
So is there any way to create a template, and import it into each page?

I Googled it, but can't seem to find anything about it. To me, it seems like a very obvious feature to have, so I figured I'd find something, but I haven't been able to.

Here's my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Intro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Top navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main body of page -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" id="sideBar">
                <h4 class="feature-title">Table of Contents</h4>
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Introduction</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Fundamentals</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Software</a></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Page Contents -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12" id="main">
                <h3 class="feature-title">Introduction</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum quam odio, quis placerat ante luctus eu. Sed aliquet dolor id sapien rutrum, id vulputate quam iaculis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--- Script Source Files -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../main.js"></script>
    <script src="template.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'd like the navbar, and sidebar to stay the same in all my pages. It's just the page contents (id="main") that is going to vary in the body. Also, I'd like the page title (in he header) to change as well. Is there some way to make that variable?
Another reason I'd prefer to do it this way is that the table of contents is going to change as I add more pages, so I don't want to have to go through each file to change the table of contents each time I make a new page.

I appreciate the help. Thanks

Edit:
Here's the CSS for template.css

```
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sideBar {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list-group-item {
  background: black;
}

.list-group-item:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FYI:** As per my suggestions, you should use some good scripting/programming languages like Ruby On Rails, Django or PHP to achieve the functionality of having one template rendering all the other page contents dynamically. So, you just need to change at your main template and will reflect on all the pages. It's a best practice.

---

Well, I am still giving you the solution as you are in the learning phase and you can achieve this using JQuery :) A good idea for just learning purpose.

> [ Not For Production Purpose - Just a solution for your problem ]

Please find the solution for your problem here on github repo. I have combined your code and created a sample project for you to work with:

It's having one template called template.html and other different content specific pages for (id="main") index.html, about.html and contact.html rendering it's own content by following template.html template.

Please have a look at this github repo:
https://github.com/ashishprajapati/template-for-basic-html

```
   git clone git@github.com:ashishprajapati/template-for-basic-html.git
```

To start the html server, please follow these steps

```
   npm install http-server -g
```

Please use this command with in the same directory where cloned project is present

```
   http-server
```

Comment: Thank you very much for going through the effort. I'm going to study it when I get home later. Also, I'll look into how to do this with PHP. Is there a name for this sort of thing in PHP, just so I know what to search for?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why isn't JQuery suitable for this? Thanks

Comment: Many Thanks Zuhaib, Please look at this medium article https://link.medium.com/60TvdQWuUW and you will easily understand the usecase of using templates in php. Basically, there is ‘include’ and ‘require’ function in php those allows us to include different pages dynamically :) Keep Learning Friend !

Comment: JQuery or javascript is not suitable for the usecase that you asked because template feature is not achievable using jquery. It requires a scripting language (php) to achieve the template feature. It will allow us to modify the html pages dynamically in backend as we want and can serve an required html page to the end user. But if you will talk about jquery then it’s not possible in the right manner. If you will check my code of index.html, you will see that I  redirected to the template.html with some params ‘partial=_index’ and then fetching the contents of index page and loading on #main id

Comment: So, you can understand. It’s achievable after writing some clever code but I am not still happy with this code style. Here, user is getting redirected to ‘template.html?partial=_index’ if you will hit index.html and then serving perfect html index page and if you will hit contact.html then it will hit ‘template.html?partial=contact’ and the serving the contact page. It’s good for your learning purpose but better to learn a scripting language like PHP, Ruby On Rails or Python/Django. Thanks :)